# readdir() fails in reading .FS_info

Tags: c

This is regard to reading a directory .FS_info. using `readdir()`. I am trying to read this .FS_info. directory and `readdir()` fails to do that. How can I read this special directory successfully?

Comment: What error does it return? Can you post some code as well?

Comment: You should properly tag your question or at least explain what environment you're working in as part of your question. C itself has no `readdir` function.

Comment: After the call to `readdir` fails, use `perror()` to learn more about why the call failed.

Answer (score 1):

From the POSIX specifications:

> Upon successful completion, readdir() returns a pointer to an object of type struct dirent. When an error is encountered, a null pointer is returned and errno is set to indicate the error.

In other words, `errno` should tell you exactly what the problem is.

My best guess is that a directory called `.FS_info` is likely to contain some system-level information about the file system itself, and probably doesn't want users mucking about in there.

But why the filesystem implementers would protect that without going the extra yards to make it invisible would be a mystery.

Bottom line, check `errno`. If that gives you no satisfaction, post the shortest pcomplete program that exhibits the behaviour, along with details on your environment (OS, filesystem type, which directory that `.FS_info` directory is in, compiler, libraries and so forth).